# Where can i see that the Application Pool is down

Tags: iis, iis-8

I'm using IIS 8 and got 404 error. after investigation, i found that the corresponded application pool was stopped (it was never started). at the moment i started it everything works good.

i couldn't find any information about that on the event log (IIS log about it only when the application pool crash and not if it never started in the first place) and couldn't see any information about it as part of the site log or as part of the "FailedReqLogFiles".

I'm wondering, how could i noticed that the problem is the application pool state without checking it specifically.

Answer (score 0):

It should be logged in Eventviewer under

> Application & Service
>   Logs->Microsoft->Windows->IIS-Configuration->Operational

Click on Operational and In the right pane select

> "Enable log"

.

Then I can see events when shutting down an AppPool.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. try to clear the log and keep the Application pool stop. now try to access the site and you will see no new logs in the event viewer.

You see the log entry you mentioned only when the Application pool going stopped from start state and not when the application pool was stopped at the beginning.

Looking forward to hear from you, thanks again.

Comment: Updated my answer. If you start/stop the appPool you will see it there. But this log is disabled by default on my machine, so enable it first.